# While loop and select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For reasons outside of my control, I need to use SQL server to essentially return numbers in a row.
Essentially from 1 to some arbitrary @param, like so:

```
|-----|
|Value|
|-----|
|  1  |
|  2  |
|  3  |
|-----|
```

I was trying to use a while loop and selecting the current index from that, however this was returning multiple result sets rather than one result set which won't work. I could accomplish what I'm trying to do by way of a temporary table however would rather not go down that path. There must be some pretty T-SQL way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`Tally Table`**. For more information, read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/) by Jeff Moden.

```
DECLARE @param INT = 1000;

WITH E1(N) AS( -- 10 rows
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b), -- 100 rows
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b), -- 1,0000 rows
E8(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E4 a CROSS JOIN E4 b), -- 100,000,000 rows
Tally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@param)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM E8 
)
SELECT * FROM Tally
```

Comment: Hi Felix, this solution also works well. I'll do some testing for performance etc to determine which one is better for my solution. Thank you!

Comment: This is better than using recursive CTes. Read this for more details: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Comment: This solution actually does work better in this case so I've changed my accepted answer. Thanks again for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to do this by selecting the start value and unioning in the previous value + 1.  This is a pretty common tactic for generating sequences.

See this article for a good example: 
https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/